# Docker Toolbox and Terminal error

Tags: docker

I'm brand new to Docker and to containers or anything ops related at all, and am playing with this tool in order to start learning. Mostly I work with Django and Frontend, so please help me understand any answer posted.  Thanks.

I installed the Docker Toolbox on my Mac (OS X) and am getting what seems to be a very common error in my terminal after I quickstart it from the Launchpad:

```
Error getting IP address: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP 
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com
```

I tried running docker-machine ip and got an error which said:

```
Error getting IP address: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
```

I've seen some broad explanations for how to fixing this, but steps and some explanation would be very helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/317

Comment: Yes, I did see that, but I do not understand the problem or the answers, and would really like to.

Answer (score 0):

Docker, as it turns out, has fantastic customer service.  They had me reinstall the toolkit, and then retry all the steps.  The first time I quickstarted the terminal, I got a time out, but it worked fine the second time.  Slow wifi may have been the problem initially.